# How to get total number of elements in an initializer-list at compile-time?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Assume i have define structure which has one array. I have initialize the array in main program. But now how can i find the number of element initialized in the array. I have created arrays of struct object too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define noOfArray 10
struct Arrays
{
   int data[100];
   int size;
   int discardArray; //1 for true and 0 for false
};

void main( )
{    
   int size=0,i,j;

   struct Arrays arrayObject[10]={
        {{1,2,3,4}},
        {{1,3,5,6,3,4}},
        {{1,6,7,8,9,10,11,43,4}}
   };

size = sizeof arrayObject[0].data / sizeof arrayObject[0].data[0];
}
```

This size gives me 100 but i need total number of element present in arrayObject[0].data.

Event tried with

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
struct Arrays arrayObject[10] = {
    {arr,sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]},
    {{1,3,5,6,3,4}},
    {{1,6,7,8,9,10,11,43,4}}
};
```

But this doesn't compile:  Near to `sizeof start` it is saying invalid initialization.

What I'm really looking for is any way to store `n` arrays, where the first array can be compared to other arrays. The element preset in the arrays with be of varying size.

Comment: But the number of elements *is* 100. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Think again! If unsure use a macro. And what is a "compile time exception"? Does your compiler crash?

Comment: Your `arrayObject[0].data` has `100` elements and all `100` elements in your array are initialized. In C language, initializing a part of an aggregate always automatically initializes the rest with `0`. It is not possible to figure out later how many elements you actually specified in the initializer. You have to keep track of that yourself, manually.

Comment: Either all or none array elements are initialized. If there is an initializer that has less elements than the array has elements, it is filled with `0` initial values for the rest. This is indistinguishable from having these `0` explicitly.

Comment: juanchopanza@ for example if you take above. arrayObject[0].data size is 100 but number of element present is 4. so i want result 4.

Comment: Olaf@ no my compiler doesn't crass. it doesn't compile. It says illegal initialization

Comment: AnT and Jens @ ok. my need is I will be having 'n' no. of arrays with different size. So examine i have hard coded it as if now, so how to store this 'n' array of different size in C language. So that first array needs to be compared with other array and i should be able to find the number of elements present in array

Answer (score 2):

Your compile time error is that you're trying to use `arr` as a value to initialize arrayObject to.  However, C only allows values that are known at compile time to be used as initializers.  `arr` is an address on the stack that won't be known until execution time, therefore it can't be used as an initializer.

You should be able to initialize to `sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]`, which will be the count of elements in the array, but you can't initialize to `arr, sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]`.

Comment: yeah true that. i was able to do that. So i just want to know how to find the size of array with optimization?

Answer (score 2):

The flaw in what you're trying to do is the way you're trying to distinguish between initialized vs. uninitialized elements.

```
int a[100] = { 1, 2 };
```

**Does** initialize all 100 elements.  The elements not mentioned in the initializer list are initialized to zero.  You can't use `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` to count initialized elements.

You *could* do something like

```
#define INIT_LIST { 1, 2, 111}  // 257
#define ASIZE 100

int big_array[ASIZE] = INIT_LIST;


// this works with gcc -O1 / -Og, but dummy is there in the object file at -O0
static const char dummy[] = INIT_LIST;
int initialized_count = sizeof(dummy);  // sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1, so no divisor is needed.

// Or even better, no dummy array in the object file even with -O0:
int initialized_count2 = sizeof((int[])INIT_LIST)/sizeof(int);
// This also avoids compiler warnings when constants in the initializer list don't fit in a char.

// in macro form: Be careful with very large initializers; this could compile slowly if you used it all over the place.
#define COUNT_INITLIST (x) (sizeof((long[])x)/sizeof(long))


// Even with optimization on, this will also compile away to just returning a constant
int initialized_in_big_array() {
    // without optimization: dummy2 is there in the object file
    // but still not copied to the stack, because of const
    const char dummy2[] = INIT_LIST;
    return sizeof(dummy2);
}
```

It turns out even at low optimization levels like `-Og`, compilers avoid emitting unused arrays entirely.  So the inline-function isn't needed.   Jens Gustedt's suggestion of casting the initializer list, so there is never an array, is the best.

Comment: There is no need to pout that in a function, `sizeof((unsigned char[])INIT_LIST)`  or `sizeof((int[])INIT_LIST)/sizeof(int)` would do.

Comment: @Jens: Nice idea, thanks.  That avoids a dummy copy of the data in the object file even at `-O0`.  Since there's no risk of that, I used `long` to avoid warnings from fitting the values into `char`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to put a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) at the end of the array. For example, if negative values are not normally allowed in the array, then you could use the value `-1` to mark the end of the array.

```
struct Arrays arrayObject[10]={
    {{1,2,3,4,-1}},
    {{1,3,5,6,3,4,-1}},
    {{1,6,7,8,9,10,11,43,4,-1}}
};
```

This allows you to use a simple `for` loop to count the number of valid entries in the array.

Comment: I can't recommend the first suggestion of manually counting the initial sizes.  Too easy to introduce hard-to-find bugs if you add an element but get the count wrong.  See my answer for how to count initializer-lists.  Sentinels are fine if O(n) to find out how many elements are in use is ok.  (e.g. if you need to scan them all in forward order anyway.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree that's it's error prone to initialize the array counts, so I took that part out.